# Java EE installer crashing on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-7

Trying to install Java EE 7/Glassfish 4 on OS 10.9 Mavericks and it crashes every time. I have tried installing the Apple JDK and the Oracle JDK and neither work. Has anyone ran into this? I remember installing on 10.8 and it worked just fine. Thanks!

Environment Variables:

$ echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Output:

```
$ chmod +x java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64.sh

$ ./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64.sh 

Extracting the installer archive...
Extracting the installer runtime... Extracting the installer
resources... Extracting the installer metadata...

Welcome to GlassFish installer

Using the user defined JAVA_HOME :
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
Entering setup... SwixML 1.5 (#144)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000119956af9, pid=5178, tid=50183
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000119956af9
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /var/folders/4t/7dky_l096m1fdl5gncg_w__80000gn/T//hs_err_pid5178.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
# /tmp/install.111513141256/install/bin/engine-wrapper: line 139:  5178 Abort trap: 6           ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_OPTIONS}
-Dinstall.engine=${theInstallEngine} -Dinstaller.resources.url=${MEDIALOC}/ -Ddefault.resources.url=file:${INSTALL_HOME}/lib/resources/ -classpath ${theCP} -Dsims.native-file-dir=${INSTALL_HOME}/lib
org.openinstaller.core.EngineBootstrap ${INSTALLPROPS}
```

Comment: What are the contents of `/var/folders/4t/7dky_l096m1fdl5gncg_w__80000gn/T//hs_err_pid5178.log`?

Comment: @admdrew whoops should have posted that, [here it is](http://pastebin.com/i5DksP04)

Comment: Found a solution and answered [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/sigsegv-when-trying-to-install-java-ee-sdk-7).

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, because I had a similar issue with another software:

try to run the installation with sudo

```
sudo [your installer]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into the same problem and thought my solution may help others in the future.

I found the answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115708/89930

To summarise, you need to set a couple of variables and then run the installer in silent mode.

Start by creating a new text file called 'silent_install_answer_file' and add the following contents, updating values as necessary:

```
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.CLUSTER_NAME=c1
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.CREATE_CLUSTER=false
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.DOMAIN_NAME=domain1
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.INSTANCE_NAME=instance1
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.SERVER_ADMIN_PORT=4848
ClusteredInstance.Configuration.SERVER_HOST_NAME=localhost
ConfigType.Option.CREATE_CLUSTEREDINSTANCE=CREATE_CLUSTEREDINSTANCE
ConfigType.Option.CREATE_DOMAIN=CREATE_DOMAIN
ConfigType.Option.CREATE_STANDALONEINSTANCE=CREATE_STANDALONEINSTANCE
ConfigType.Option.NO_CONFIGURATION=NO_CONFIGURATION
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_PASSWORD_REENTER=password
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_PORT=4848
Domain.Configuration.ADMIN_USER=admin
Domain.Configuration.CREATE_SERVICE=false
Domain.Configuration.DOMAIN_NAME=domain1
Domain.Configuration.HTTP_PORT=8080
Domain.Configuration.SERVICE_NAME=domain1Service
Domain.Configuration.START_SERVER=false
InstallHome.directory.INSTALL_HOME=/usr/local/glassfish4
InstallType.Option.CONFIG_ONLY=CONFIG_ONLY
InstallType.Option.INSTALL_AND_CONFIG=INSTALL_AND_CONFIG
InstallType.Option.INSTALL_ONLY=INSTALL_ONLY
InstallUserType.Option.ADVANCED_USER=ADVANCED_USER
InstallUserType.Option.BASIC_USER=BASIC_USER
JDKSelection.directory.HIDDEN_JDK=
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_FROM_LIST_CHOICE=false
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_LIST=
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_TYPE_IN=
JDKSelection.directory.JDK_TYPED_IN_CHOICE=false
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.CREATE_NEWACCT=CREATE_NEWACCT
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.DUMMY_PROP=
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.SKIP_REGISTRATION=SKIP_REGISTRATION
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.USE_EXISTINGACCT=USE_EXISTINGACCT
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.USERNAME=
RegistrationOptions.regoptions.USERPASSWORD=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.COMPANYNAME=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.COUNTRY_DROP_DOWN=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.COUNTRY=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.EMAIL=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.FIRSTNAME=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.LASTNAME=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.PASSWORD=
SOAccountCreation.accountinfo.REENTERPASSWORD=
StandaloneInstance.Configuration.INSTANCE_NAME=instance1
StandaloneInstance.Configuration.SERVER_ADMIN_PORT=4848
StandaloneInstance.Configuration.SERVER_HOST_NAME=localhost
UpdateTool.Configuration.ALLOW_UPDATE_CHECK=true
UpdateTool.Configuration.BOOTSTRAP_UPDATETOOL=true
UpdateTool.Configuration.PROXY_HOST=
UpdateTool.Configuration.PROXY_PORT=
```

Check that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set appropriately:

`export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"`

Create the `/Users/username/temp` directory if it does not already exist (`mkdir /Users/username/temp`).

Lastly, run the installer with sudo.  You may also need to set the DISPLAY variable at the same time:

`$ sudo DISPLAY=:0 ./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64.sh -a silent_install_answer_file -l /Users/username/temp -s`

The installer may take a few minutes to complete and, as it is running in silent mode, you may not see much output during that time, so be patient.

If you have trouble running the installer in silent mode, the GlassFish installer documentation may be of some use to you: https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/installation-guide.pdf

A seemingly related question: [java ee install failing on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21035498/1341469)

Hope that helps someone!